# Should I add publish_actions for review after migrating old app to Graph API v2.2?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been updating few web apps to the latest Facebook Graph API - v2.2. Those sites work and some of them have opengraph action video.watches ("Watch"). It's approved and works.

Recently I got a generic Facebook email that one or more of my apps are using permissions that have to be reviewed or they will stop working on some date. As those apps are quite old they don't have publish_actions in the review set (and that's the only extra permission in that video.watches websites). So now - does Facebook wants that publish_actions to be added to the review or it's something else (they could be more specific)?

Answer (score 0):

You would require publish_actions to continue to post Open Graph actions to Facebook. Please submit for review.